# Can anyone explain this Challenge solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I will attach image of challenge solution that i cannot understand this solution not the challenge itself

Code :

```js
function array(num,length){
  return [...Array(length).map((_,i) => num * (i+1)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up the documentation before asking? [`...`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#parameters), [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This is very straight-forward (if the syntax errors were fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are something wrong with the syntax: There is both a missing `]` and `)`.

There is a function called "array" (maybe it is not the best name...). It takes two parameters: a number (num) and a length (length), both numbers.

`length` is used for defining and array (`Array(length)`). So length=4 will result in an array: `[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]`. `map()` is a function that takes an array and returns an array with a similar length. The array returned by `map()` contains numbers that are calulated based on the index (the `i`) and the parameter `num`, so first `0*3`, then `1*3`, then `2*3`. The array is then returned as the "result" of calling the function "array".

Here I print out the array in the console:

```js
function array(num, length){
  return [...Array(length)].map((_,i) => num * (i+1))
}

console.log(array(3, 4));
```